# Android App crash when setting debuggable to False

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

MainActivity closed at runtime witout reason  when setting debuggable to False in project gradle file. but when the App is debuggable it's work fine.
I have checked logcat but nothing found to help me.
anyone have an idea ?

the logcat output is:

```
    02-07 11:08:48.157 13586-13586/? E/Zygote: v2
02-07 11:08:48.157 13586-13586/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10177
02-07 11:08:48.157 13586-13586/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-07 11:08:48.167 13586-13586/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0031
02-07 11:08:48.167 13586-13586/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-07 11:08:48.167 13586-13586/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew 
02-07 11:08:48.217 13586-13586/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-07 11:08:48.217 13586-13586/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-07 11:08:48.287 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
02-07 11:08:48.287 13586-13586/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew rsrc of package ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew
02-07 11:08:48.287 13586-13586/? D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
02-07 11:08:48.297 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
02-07 11:08:48.357 13586-13586/? I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
02-07 11:08:48.357 13586-13586/? I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
02-07 11:08:48.367 13586-13586/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew rsrc of package ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew
02-07 11:08:48.387 13586-13586/? I/GAv4: Google Analytics 8.4.87 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
02-07 11:08:48.387 13586-13586/? I/GAv4:   adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
02-07 11:08:48.387 13586-13586/? I/GAv4:   adb logcat -s GAv4
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew, Feature store :{}
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew rsrc of package ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew
02-07 11:08:48.447 13586-13586/? D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
02-07 11:08:48.757 13586-13586/? D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-07 11:08:48.757 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@affb32a
02-07 11:08:48.757 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3f2451b
02-07 11:08:48.757 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3f2451b
02-07 11:08:48.957 13586-13586/? D/Minikin: FontFamily bestFont == NULL, so return vacant FakedFont
02-07 11:08:48.957 13586-13586/? D/Minikin: FontFamily bestFont == NULL, so return vacant FakedFont
02-07 11:08:48.957 13586-13586/? D/Minikin: FontFamily bestFont == NULL, so return vacant FakedFont
02-07 11:08:49.007 13586-13586/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew time:245262389
02-07 11:08:49.027 13586-13586/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
02-07 11:08:49.047 13586-13586/? D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
02-07 11:08:49.047 13586-13586/? D/TelegramNew: mainline 1
02-07 11:08:49.047 13586-13586/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew rsrc of package ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew
02-07 11:08:49.097 13586-13586/? D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-07 11:08:49.097 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@3f1b83c
02-07 11:08:49.097 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@e75e9c5
02-07 11:08:49.097 13586-13586/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@e75e9c5
02-07 11:08:49.097 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew.NavigationDrawerFragment isFragment :true
02-07 11:08:49.117 13586-13586/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
02-07 11:08:49.147 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew.FragmentMain isFragment :true
02-07 11:08:49.157 13586-13586/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : ir.androidsoftware.TelegramNew.FragmentSeeChannels isFragment :true
02-07 11:08:49.397 13586-13586/? D/TelegramNewLeft: CheckLefts killed()
02-07 11:08:49.397 13586-13586/? D/TelegramNewLeft: CheckLefts Stop()
02-07 11:08:50.577 13586-13624/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 60 with tag b59f8cea00000000{3047132394,0} uid -1, pid: 13586, getuid(): 10177
02-07 11:08:58.507 13586-13642/? D/Minikin: FontCollection getFamilyForChar is NULL, so assign fakedFont.font = NULL
02-07 11:08:58.507 13586-13642/? E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbba length 2
02-07 11:08:58.507 13586-13642/? D/Minikin: FontCollection getFamilyForChar is NULL, so assign fakedFont.font = NULL
02-07 11:08:58.507 13586-13642/? E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbba length 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by closed? is it crash ? And are you setting debuggable in manifest ?

Comment: Yes , it's crash.

Comment: Then do post the complete stack trace, the one you added doesnt resolve the cause and beginning of crash!

Comment: the problem is activity closed and it's not show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.I have added this code in BaseActivity that mainActivity inherit from it:

```
if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Secure.CheckPckNm(this);
        Secure.CheckAppSign(this);
}
```

The CheckAppSign finish mainActivity if signature is invalid.
I had forgotten that code :-) .

Answer (score 0):

hi i see in your answer you using this

```
 if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {     
    Secure.CheckPckNm(this);   
    Secure.CheckAppSign(this); 
  }
```

but this is not usefull because  hacker/cracker can change BuildConfig class and if he change Debug value to `true`
this code not executed 
you should check debug signature too